# How is the data returning from Firebase Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I get each profile back as objects and put them into an array list. The first println shows size as 1 then the second one shows the size as 0. How is this possible?... My Profile class has getters for each attribute and an empty Profile constructor.

```
  // Initialize Profiles Array, global variable in my project
    ArrayList<Profile> profileObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    // GET FIREBASE PROFILE DATA, PUT INTO ARRAY
    ref.child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Profile profiles = child.getValue(Profile.class);
                profileObjects.add(profiles);
            }
            System.out.println("GETTTINGGGGG BACKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK 1: " + profileObjects.size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    System.out.println("GETTTINGGGGG BACKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK 2: " + profileObjects.size());
```

Picture of my data in Firebase:

[image: Firebase]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get all user's data then get "pic" from it or you can get only "pic" reference.

```
ref.child("Users").child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // to get all user object ,then you can get pic url from it by calling user.getPic() for example
        Usermodel user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usermodel .class);
        String picUrl = user.getPic();

        // or you can get "pic" value only
        String picUrl = dataSnapshot.child("pic").getValue(String.class);
     }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

your `UserModel` class could be like this

```
public class UserModel {
public UserModel() {
}

String name, age, gender, pic;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getPic() {
    return pic;
}

public void setPic(String pic) {
    this.pic = pic;
}
```

}

Comment: Im still getting null. It says "no setter/field in User.class". I have setters for all the user attributes in my database. Do I have have to make one big setter constructer for the User object?

Comment: you need to make class for your model with it's setters and getters to map the data that comes from the serve apart from your database.

Comment: Glad to help. If you want, you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you get **null** caue of

```
        String picUrl = dataSnapshot.child("Uid").child("pic").toString();
```

where Uid is Just String not variable 
you need to use

```
    for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) 
      {
                // each child is user
                //   if you have use model do this
                                Usermodel um = child.getValue(Usermodel .class);
                       String picurl = um.getpicurl(); 

         }
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! In my UserModel, I just need getters and setters for all key fields of User in the DB right?

Comment: Right  ... create your own model

Comment: Got It THANK YOU! If i had enough reputation points I would up arrow your response. When I get them I will!